# How to pass multiple Columns as features in a Logistic Regression Classifier in Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, logistic-regression

I am trying to run Logistic regression with a simple data set to understand the syntax of pyspark. 
I have data which looks has 11 columns where the first 10 columns are features and the last column(11th column) is the label.
I want to pass these 10 columns as features and the 11th column as label.
But I only know to pass as a single column to pass as a feature using `featuresCol="col_header_name"`
I have read the data from a csv file using pandas but I have converted it into RDD.
here is the code:

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('abc.csv')
sc = SparkContext("local", "App Name")
sql = SQLContext(sc)
spDF = sql.createDataFrame(data)
tri=LogisticRegression(maxIter=10,regParam=0.01,featuresCol="single_column",labelCol="label")
lr_model = tri.fit(spDF)
```

if I use `featuresCol=[list_of_header_names]` I get errors.
I have used sk-learn which has really simple syntax something like:

```
reg=LogisticRegression()
reg=reg.fit(Dataframe_of_features,Label_array)
```

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: `TypeError: Invalid param value given for param "featuresCol". Could not convert <class 'list'> to string type`
Which makes some sense because according to the syntax, `featuresCol="name_of_column"` which is a string.

Comment: Is that really the error, when you have `featuresCol="single_column"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to combine all the columns into one array of feature using Vector Assembler.

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=[list_of_header_names],outputCol="features")
spDF = assembler.transform(spDF)
```

You can then pass that assembled array of all the variables as an input to the logistic regression.

```
tri=LogisticRegression(maxIter=10,
                       regParam=0.01,
                       featuresCol="features",
                       labelCol="label")
lr_model = tri.fit(spDF)
```

Comment: It works, Thanks! Just one more thing.what are MaxIter, RegParam and ElasticNetParam ?

Comment: MaxIter is the number of maximum iteration, RegParam is the regularization parameter. Elastic Net Param specifies if you want the loss function to be L1 or L2.

Comment: thanks but I do know the full forms! I wanted to know their purpose.